# Moving from flex 3.2 to flex 3.5?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, mxml, lcds

what changes I need to make?

1. What can be the possible issues in upgrading ?
2. Benefits of upgrading from **flex** 3.2 to 3.5.

Comment: You talking about flex, the lexical analyzer generator or Adobe Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience there wasn't any changes with upgrades within 3.x SDKs. And there wasn't any significant changes for me.

So I recommend you to upgrade to 4.1 or even to 4.5 directly. It will take rather big amount of work but give you a lot of advantages :)

Comment: ok, so if i go with flex 4.1 what changes i need to do in my already running project.but if i still use my MX components in flex 4 then what will be the advantage of Using sdk 4.

Comment: can you please tell me in more datail that what changes we need to make in the components or anywhere else in the project if we move from Sdk 3.2 to 3.5

Comment: If you want to upgrade from 3.2 to 3.5 just add new SDK into your IDE and change SDK version for your project. An if you're using any build script (Maven or Ant) there shouldn't be any problems to change version. If there will be some minor incompatibilities compiler will inform you immediately and you'll fix them without any problem. Anyway you can roll back in any moment without problems. So I recommend you just to try. It won't take more than 1-2 hours from you :)

Comment: If you want to migrate to 4.1 use the following instructions http://www.learnosity.com/techblog/index.cfm/2010/3/21/Flex-3-to-Flex-4-Migration-Howto and "Migrating Flex 3 applications to Flex 4" chapter of official guide http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/FeaturesAndMigration/flex_4_features.pdf

Comment: I found that some component SWC being moved to a different location from 3.2. For instance: They moved the AdvancedDataGrid into the datavisualization.swc.
2-->how about the custom component  that extend the existing components. will they be effected when moving from sdk 3.2 to 3.5.

Comment: There is no problem with SWCs repackaging. All the classes there are the same. And your custom components should work fine.

Comment: Have you any ideas about moving from Sdk 3.2 to 3.4  thanks in Advance for the help. Constantiner

Comment: I listed my ideas above: it should be no pain. Just change SDK version existing project and go on! Have you started your migration or still planning it?

Comment: When I upgraded to flex 4 from 3 I found styling to be very different on a lot of the premade objects . So if you are not using default styles be ready to do some style adjustments

Comment: Hi Constantiner ,What are the advantages you were talking about while moving from flex 3 to 4..we are planning to upgrade,it can be 3 to 4 or within 3.x ...so just gathering some info before making a move.

Comment: ""@ The_asMan"".what other changes you made,,what all effort i need to make,, you would have read the discussion B/W me and Constantiner.If you can add some more points to it,it will be a great help.. Thanks in Advance

Comment: The main advantages of Flex SDK 4.x are new customization features. New skinning/layouting changes the game. If you'll try that flexibility you'll never want to go back. Among other features are new States, TLF, CSS improvements. You'll definitely should try it. Just review this documentation http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/FeaturesAndMigration/flex_4_features.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't any major changes between 3.2 and 3.5.  I'm fairly certain that if you were to recompile your project in 3.5, you won't notice any difference.  The change was mostly a few small bug fixes here and there, like most of 3.* updates.

Comment: ok, so if i go with flex 4.1 what changes i need to do in my already running project.but if i still use my MX components in flex 4 then what will be the advantage of Using sdk 4

Comment: Hey Jax can you tell me that what benefits do i get if i upgrade from sdk 3.2 to sdk 3.4 ??  Thanks in Advance